# Villeta's Soup of Primes

Tags: mathematics, number-theory, primes

i) Hidden in this 8 x 8 board are the first 31 primes starting with 2 and up to to 127. They occupy adjacent, non-overlapping cells (up to 3), and are read horizontally (from left to right) or vertically (from top to bottom). Find them!

ii) Prepare a similar soup, but in a 10 x 10 board filled with the first 43 primes (2 to 191) such that these primes can be located uniquely inside the soup. Make it as hard as possible to identify primes!

[image]

Comment: This sounds like it should really be two separate questions

Comment: Question 2 isn't too well defined, mainly because it's impossible to quantify how 'hard' puzzles are. Largest number of red herrings?

Answer (score 11):

i)

> You can look at the 0's in the grid to uniquely identify 101, 103, 107, 109. That gives us a good starting point and you can continue from the immediate surroundings to fill up the rest of the grid.
>
>  [image]

ii)

> Starting from the original grid and tweaking it a bit:
>
> ```
>  1138829711
>  1113961178
>  9794167291
>  1109174711
>  2771033155
>  7310753317
>  1019233159
>  1377163543
>  3173139191
>  1149167137
> ```